# How to customize styles from navigation menu in Blank theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, less-css

I've figured out how to change background color in navigation menu by changing values from the navigation UI library (LESS file).
Now I want to add top and bottom borders to this menu, how can I achieve that?
Is it possible to add a new property like "border-top-style" (or any other) to the navigation styles? and how it is done?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend or overwrite the `_navigation.less` file. (you can find this in `vendor > magento > theme-frontend-blank > web > css > source` )

If you want to just change a few elements from this file, create a `_navigation_extend.less` file in your themes `web > css > source` file and add your styles in there. If you want to overwrite it entirely, don't add `_extend` to the end of the file name.

You will need to import this file into your `_extend.less` file using `@import '_navigation_extend.less';` or `@import '_navigation.less';` so that your changes are included in your theme.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've already made some changes to navigation menu extending **existing** variables/properties from the `navigation.less` file but I dont know yet how to add **new** properties (border-top-style) to the navigation menu.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've answered your own question here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106569/how-to-utilise-the-existing-less-variables-in-my-new-less-file/109808#109808

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I dont know yet how to add **new** properties (border-top-style) to the navigation menu. I know the code should be in the `_navigation_extend.less` file but I have not identified where the border-top-style property is defined, so I can change/extend it.

Comment: What is your parent theme? I haven't seen a `border-top-style` variable yet, the only ones I've come across so far are: `border-color__base, border-width__base, hr__border-color, hr__border-style, hr__border-width`.These were in the `_typography.less` file in `lib > variables`. If it's a **new** property I'd create your own variable / add it into your `_navigation_extend.less` file. I've added my navigation border to my `_navigation_extend.less` file like so:
`.navigation {
 border-bottom: @border-width__base solid @color-black;
}`

Maybe it's not the right way but it works for me.

Comment: Parent theme is Blank. In `navigation.less` (line 11) there is a `@navigation__border: '  '` variable. In my `_navigation_extend.less` set it to `@navigation__border: 3px solid blue;` but it does not work. I'll try the way you did it. Thanks